# Android Studio how to boot on quick mode after this error?

Tags: android, kotlin

Here is my first issue with Android Studio. I'm starting to learn Kotlin, I was following a tutorial, but then I decided to start again with a template, so after start a template I got this error when I tried to launch the emulator. I have no idea why is happening that.

```
10/17 23:24:34: Launching 'app' on Nexus 6P API 27.
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.
Installation failed due to: ''cmd package install-create -r -t -S 2918030' returns error 'Unknown failure: cmd: Can't find service: package''
Retry
```

If I start the emulation in the cold boot option, there is no issue. I would like to start it in the quick boot mode.

Comment: Please clarify why you want to boot in quick mode and how is related with the error

Comment: Because I think it's annoying to boot the emulator from 0 every single time I want to test anything for the app. Also it might be troublesome if it can not work from the last state it had.

How is related, I don't know. It just works in that mode, but I don't know why.